# Issue with canvas.toDataUrl: error when the canvas contains a tag image with base64 data

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, todataurl, canvg

i'm using this function to convert an svg to a jpeg (it includes canvg):

```
    svgToDataUrl(svg, format = 'jpeg') {
        var id = new Date();
        var canvasElement = $(`<canvas id="${id}" width="1198px" 
height="1694px"></canvas>`).appendTo('#resultsInterface');
        let canvas = canvasElement[0];
        window.canvg(canvas, svg);
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(`image/${format}`, 0.98);
        canvasElement.remove();
        return imgData;
     }
```

The SVG variable in a SVG image previously generated.
Now, it works properly but, if the SVG contains a tag  with an href in base64 format:

```
<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORblablabla..."></image>
```

The result is blank. I've tried to check the canvas generated (before it is removed) and is just fine but for some reason canvas.toDataURL seems not working in this case.

Any clue?

Thanks
Daniele

Comment: Why do you use `Date` object as value for `id` attribute?

Comment: Canvg function will be async in this case. I don't remember exactly the syntax to add a callback, but you can find easily in the docs

Comment: I've added the callback and now it works. Thanks!